# How do I create a PSP emulator?

Tags: emulation, device-emulation

I know that I need to know at least C and Assembly. In your own opinion what else does one need to know apart from knowing how to program in C and Assembly efficiently? Are there any books you can suggest to get me started? I also read that you need to know about the hardware architecture of the platform you are emulating. Would you also recommend the books listed **[here](http://web.archive.org/web/20111219055347/http://www.noxa.org/blog/2011/08/21/emulation-books/)**?

Answer (score 2):

**For experts only**

You would have to know all the inner workings and hardware details of PSP, which are business secrets of Sony and therefore not published. The way most emulators are made is *reverse engineering*, a process in which the device itself is disassembled and its inner workings are studied. That includes analyzing the chips thoroughly, reading the contents of ROM chips and sometimes even deciphering encrypted data. Full analysis usually requires specialized equipment and years of engineering experience.

Comment: Then I have to read up on reverse engineering first before I even start writing the emulator.